# One jQuery Working, twin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have two jQuery scripts running. One of them works, yet the other does not. They are essentially identical twins, except with different element ids. I have verified that the ids are correct. The working one is above, and the non-functioning twin is below. Why isn't it working? Here it is in a jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/TJonS/MR9mg/

```
            $('#Axiom-DAdjustableOA').click(function() {
                if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                    $('#Short13').slideUp('fast');
                    $('#Standard15').slideUp('fast');
                    $('#Short14').slideUp('fast');
                    $('#Standard16').slideUp('fast');
                    $('#Short16').slideUp('fast');
                    $('#Standard17').slideUp('fast');
                    $('#Standard13').slideUp('fast');
                    $('#Extended15').slideUp('fast');
                    $('#Standard11').slideUp('fast');
                    $('#Extended13').slideUp('fast');
                    $('#DegreesOfOffset').slideDown('fast');
                } else {
                    $('#Short13').slideDown('fast');
                    $('#Standard15').slideDown('fast');
                    $('#Short14').slideDown('fast');
                    $('#Standard16').slideDown('fast');
                    $('#Short16').slideDown('fast');
                    $('#Standard17').slideDown('fast');
                    $('#Standard13').slideDown('fast');
                    $('#Extended15').slideDown('fast');
                    $('#Standard11').slideDown('fast');
                    $('#Extended13').slideDown('fast');
                    $('#DegreesOfOffset').slideDown('fast');
                }
            });


            $('#Duo').click(function() {
                if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                    $('#Magnesium').slideUp('fast');
                    $('#Aluminum').slideUp('fast');
                    $('#Short14').slideUp('fast');
                    $('#Standard16').slideUp('fast');
                    $('#Short16').slideUp('fast');
                    $('#Standard17').slideUp('fast');
                    $('#Standard13').slideUp('fast');
                    $('#Extended15').slideUp('fast');
                    $('#Standard11').slideUp('fast');
                    $('#Extended13').slideUp('fast');
                    $('#DegreesOfOffset').slideUp('fast');
                } else {
                    $('#Magnesium').slideDown('fast');
                    $('#Aluminum').slideDown('fast');
                    $('#Short13').slideDown('fast');
                    $('#Standard15').slideDown('fast');
                    $('#Short14').slideDown('fast');
                    $('#Standard16').slideDown('fast');
                    $('#Short16').slideDown('fast');
                    $('#Standard17').slideDown('fast');
                    $('#Standard13').slideDown('fast');
                    $('#Extended15').slideDown('fast');
                    $('#Standard11').slideDown('fast');
                    $('#Extended13').slideDown('fast');
                    $('#DegreesOfOffset').slideDown('fast');
                }
            });
```

Comment: can you create a jsbin or jsfiddle or the like?

Comment: Absolutely. It will be on jsfiddle. Let me get the link

Comment: Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TJonS/MR9mg/

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: The Axiom script slides the commanded elements on check. The duo doesn't

Comment: Ok. This is very embarrassing and weird. The jsfiddle works, but the [site](http://tjs.neocities.org/test.html) doesn't.

Comment: Updatee your fiddle, but it still "doesn't work" (your click elements are not to be seen): http://jsfiddle.net/MR9mg/1/

Comment: can you take a look at it on the site? The address is in my last comment.

Comment: Your live site works, try to clear your cache?

Comment: It's broken on the test page in Firefox (http://imgur.com/nYCoqbz); in Chrome latest, it works just fine? You should use classes instead of ids for type of thing as well; all of that repetitiveness should be a clue something is going sideways.

Comment: Thanks. Clearing the cache helped, but "Z-12 OA","Z-12-D", and the last two, 20.50 and 20.50OA still don't work. My code is all there in the jsfiddle. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok. I have always been taught to use classes

Comment: Don't use spaces in ID, space character is not a valid for ID attribute.

Comment: Got it. If I take those out, will
 it do any better?

Comment: Remove points too from ID, or you must escape them in jQuery selectors

Comment: Are these the points: - - -?

Comment: no . like this #20.50OA

Comment: Oh the periods. Or points

Comment: Alright. I have it fixed now. Edward, you are the man! If you leave an answer, I will gladly accept and upvote it.

Comment: @TJonS, see this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jSsvx/2/

Comment: Thanks. It works too. Your code is SO much cleaner than mine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problems you have to:

- start by clearing your cache
- avoid to use spaces in ID (e.g. #Z-12 OA), space character is not a valid for ID
  attribute
- avoid to use points in ID (eg #20.50OA), or you must escape them in
  jQuery selectors

But think about refactor your code to have it more simple to maintain.